# How do I change the row and column data in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

If I have a 5x5 2D array, how do I compare the values in each of the array[row][col] and make a decision based on the result? In this case, if array[row][col] is greater than zero, replace that data with zero. This is what I have so far.

```
for(int row = 0; row<3; row++){
    System.out.println();
    for(int col= 0; col<5;col++){

        System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");

        if(array[row][col] > 0){
            array[row][col] = 0; //replace with 0
            System.out.print(array[row][col]; //print result
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example iterating over a test 5x5 array and replacing any non-zero values with 0s. You can use the Arrays deepToString method to print the result.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NDArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {
            { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 2, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 3, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
        };
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
            if (arr[row][col] > 0) {
                arr[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
}
}
```

Comment: Chad, thanks for your help. I appreciate that. I think I had a print statement that confused my output.